# How to work with JButton?

Tags: java, swing, colors, jbutton

Hi I am trying to make java desk top application where I am using 3 JButtons. I want that when I click any  JButton it should change the color of that button and if I click on any other JButton then previous clicked button should be like  before and recently clicked button change its color until another JButton is clicked

How can I achieve this

here is my button code

```
b1 = new JButton("Ok");
b1.setBounds(800, 725, 100, 40);
b1.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
c.add(b1);

b2 = new JButton("Print");
b2.setBounds(925, 725, 100, 40);
b2.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
c.add(b2);
b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
        b1.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"Welcome to allhabad High Court");
    }
});

b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
        b2.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"Welcome to allhabad High Court");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
       b1.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
       b2.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"Welcome to allhabad High Court");
}
});

    b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
       b2.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
      b1.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"Welcome to allhabad High Court");
}
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This is actually more tricky then it sounds.  Some look and feels don't use the `background` color property when rendering the buttons (for example Windows)

A possible solution might be to use a `ButtonGroup` and `JToggleButton`, which will ensure that only one button is selected at a time and allow you to monitor the selected states of the buttons, for example...

[image: toggle]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JToggleButton;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class ToggleButton {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ToggleButton();
    }

    public ToggleButton() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                final JToggleButton b1 = new JToggleButton("Ok");
                b1.setContentAreaFilled(false);
                b1.setOpaque(true);
                b1.getModel().addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                        if (b1.isSelected()) {
                            b1.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                        } else {
                            b1.setBackground(null);
                        }
                    }
                });
                final JToggleButton b2 = new JToggleButton("Print");
                b2.setContentAreaFilled(false);
                b2.setOpaque(true);
                b2.getModel().addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                        if (b2.isSelected()) {
                            b2.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                        } else {
                            b2.setBackground(null);
                        }
                    }
                });

                ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
                bg.add(b1);
                bg.add(b2);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                frame.add(b1);
                frame.add(b2);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Another solution might be to use `JRadioButton` instead, which is generally used to indicate a single selection from a group of options.

See [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)